# Ejabberd Disco Iteam not coming

Tags: mysql, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

Vrsion: `17.11`

Platform : ubuntu `16.04`

With the mod_muc configuration, sometimes disco items does not load at all. 
Here is a configuration I have used for disco items. Here is a crash log I found while crashes

```
mod_muc:
  db_type: sql
  default_room_options:
    - allow_subscription: true
    - mam: true
  access_admin:
    - allow: admin
  access_create: muc_create
  access_persistent: muc_create
  history_size: 100
  max_rooms_discoitems: 1000
  max_user_conferences: 50
  max_users_presence: 50
```

Also, while joining same muc which was earlier available does not get connection. If I restart the server, things works well and again after certain times muc s doesn't come

Error Log:

```
Stopping MUC room x@conference.host.com
2018-07-27 12:57:39.972 [error] <0.32056.26> gen_fsm <0.32056.26> in state normal_state terminated with reason: bad return value: ok
2018-07-27 12:57:39.972 [error] <0.32056.26>@p1_fsm:terminate:760 CRASH REPORT Process <0.32056.26> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: bad return value: ok in p1_fsm:terminate/8 line 760


 2018-07-30 05:12:12 =ERROR REPORT====
 ** State machine <0.9190.27> terminating 
 ** Last event in was {route,<<>>,{iq,<<"qM1F3-119">>,set,<<"en">>,{jid,<<"usr_name">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<"1140">>,<<"usr_name">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<"1140">>},{jid,<<"planet_discovery1532511384">>,<<"conference.x.y.com">>,<<>>,<<"planet_discovery1532511384">>,<<"conference.x.y.com">>,<<>>},[{xmlel,<<"query">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:2">>}],[{xmlel,<<"set">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">>}],[{xmlel,<<"max">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"30">>}]},{xmlel,<<"after">>,[],[]}]},{xmlel,<<"x">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:x:data">>},{<<"type">>,<<"submit">>}],[{xmlel,<<"field">>,[{<<"var">>,<<"FORM_TYPE">>},{<<"type">>,<<"hidden">>}],[{xmlel,<<"value">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:2">>}]}]}]}]}],#{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,46291,27829}}}}
 ** When State == normal_state
 **      Data  == {state,<<"planet_discovery1532511384">>, 
 <<"conference.x.y.com">>,<<"x.y.com">>,{all,muc_create,[{allow, 
[{acl,admin}]}],muc_create},{jid,<<"planet_discovery1532511384">>,<<"conference.x.y.com">>,<<>>,<<"planet_discovery1532511384">>,<<"conference.x.y.com">>,<<>>},{config,<<"Planet Discovery">>,<<>>,true,true,true,anyone,true,true,false,true,true,true,false,true,true,true,true,false,<<>>,true,[moderator,participant,visitor],true,1800,200,false,<<>>,{0,nil},true},{dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[[{<<"usr_name">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<"1140">>}|{x.y.com,{jid,<<"usr_name">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<"1140">>,<<"usr_name">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<"1140">>},<<"usr_name@x.y.com/1140">>,moderator,{presence,<<"qM1F3-116">>,available,<<"en">>,{jid,<<"usr_name">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<"1140">>,<<"usr_name">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<"1140">>},{jid,<<"planet_discovery1532511384">>,<<"conference.x.y.com">>,<<"usr_name@x.y.com/1140">>,<<"planet_discovery1532511384">>,<<"conference.x.y.com">>,<<"usr_name@x.y.com/1140">>},undefined,[],undefined,[{xmlel,<<"c">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/caps">>},{<<"hash">>,<<"sha-1">>},{<<"node">>,<<"http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack">>},{<<"ver">>,<<"p801v5l0jeGbLCy09wmWvQCQ7Ok=">>}],[]},{vcard_xupdate,{<<>>,<<>>},undefined}],#{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,46291,27829}}}}]],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},nil,{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},{dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[[<<"usr_name@x.y.com/1140">>,{<<"usr_name">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<"1140">>}]],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},{dict,3,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[[{<<"usr_name">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<>>}|{owner,<<>>}]],[],[],[[{<<"miga8747b6">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<>>}|{owner,<<>>}]],[],[],[],[[{<<"ruba32cc6e">>,<<"x.y.com">>,<<>>}|{owner,<<>>}]],[]}}},{lqueue,{{[],[]},0,unlimited},1000},[],<<>>,false,nil,none,undefined}
** Reason for termination = 
** {bad_return_value,ok}
2018-07-30 05:12:12 =CRASH REPORT====
crasher:
  initial call: mod_muc_room:init/1
  pid: <0.9190.27>
  registered_name: []
  exception exit: {{bad_return_value,ok},[{p1_fsm,terminate,8,[{file,"src/p1_fsm.erl"},{line,760}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
  ancestors: ['mod_muc_x.y.com',ejabberd_gen_mod_sup,ejabberd_sup,<0.32330.26>]
  messages: []
  links: []
  dictionary: [{'$internal_queue_len',0}]
  trap_exit: true
  status: running
  heap_size: 6772
  stack_size: 27
  reductions: 3310
neighbours:
2018-07-30 12:41:56 =ERROR REPORT====
```

Comment: You should check the log file for errors.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond : I have just updated the logs.

Comment: crash.log has more information

Comment: Added crash logs as well

Comment: Hi MickaëlRémond. Can you help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

What ejabberd version? and how did you install it?

The syntax of your default_room_options are wrong, did you really use that config like that?

And what changes you made from a stock installation? I mean: did you setup a cluster of several nodes, did you enable other modules that may interfere with mod_muc...?

And most importantly: you have setup the max_rooms_discoitems to 10000. How many rooms does the service have? That option should be set to a small value, because requesting discoitems for 10.000 rooms means requesting information to each single room, and that means 10.000 queries, and that can have unknown consequences. Does your problem reproduce if you set a low value, like 100?

Comment: I am using 17.11 version , please let me know your ejaberd.yml file configuration for mod_muc please?

Comment: I have reduced other configurations , but still error is same.

Comment: So, you set max_rooms_discoitems: 100, and Disco Items still produce that error? And same if you set 10? How many rooms exist in that MUC service? What happens if you have only 4 o 5 rooms?